# Term meta not saved when adding the first category

Tags: terms, term-meta

I'd like to give administrators and editors the option to specify colors for categories they create. They'd enter in the hex colors they prefer e.g. #000.

I'm experiencing an odd issue in that the first time I create a category and pop in a color, it doesn't save the term meta but does on every subsequent category I create. For example, if the first category is titled 'Category 1' with the hex color `#1A282A`, no term meta is saved.

If I then create a second category named 'Category 2' with a hex color, it saves it and it continues to do so with any future category. I can't quite figure out why the term meta isn't added or updated when it's the first category.

What am I missing?

```
function mt_set_color_category( $term ) {
    $color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id ?? false, '_term_color', true );
    if( $color == '' ) $color = '#ffffff';
  ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="term-color">Category Color</label></th>
        <td>
            <input name="_term_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $color ); ?>" class="color" id="term-color" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'mt_set_color_category' );
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'mt_set_color_category' );

function mt_set_color_category_term_meta( $term_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['_term_color'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_term_color'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, '_term_color', sanitize_hex_color( $_POST['_term_color'] ) );
    } else {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, '_term_color' );
    }
}
add_action( 'created_category', 'mt_set_color_category_term_meta' );
add_action( 'edited_category',  'mt_set_color_category_term_meta' );
```

Comment: @SallyCJ - I came across your answer - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407671/where-to-use-nonce as an example. Am I overlooking anything?

Comment: The hooks should be [`create_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/) and [`edit_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_taxonomy/) 
 You've added  `ed` to the naming which are ***different*** hooks that fire ***after the term cache has been cleaned*** :-) (also note that these are generic template hooks and you can use them for other taxonomies than just "category")

Comment: @jave.web, thanks. I did try it with `create_category` and `edit_category` and it results in the same behavior. Also, what difference does it make after the term cache has been cleared?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the question my comment was off topic - does the saving on "Category 1" NEVER works? Or does it start to work after creating "Category 2"? Have you tried changing the title, and mainly, the slug of the first category? (btw: the cache thing could be different if you would want to display data in the same call that saves them (I'm guessing))

Comment: @jave.web, it never works when saving the first category with the new field filled in. It does work after the first category has been added i.e. when I add the second category with a value in the new field. Yes, I have tried different titles and slugs. The same behavior occurs with a fresh installation of WordPress with no plugins (other than the default).

Comment: and what happens if you delete the first category (that doesn't work) - does the second category stop working? Or does it keep working?
(btw by any chance - I hope you are not renaming the non-deletable first category to Category 1 expecting it to behave standardly)

Comment: @jave.web, sorry for not replying sooner. If the first is deleted, the second repeats the behavior and no, the first category i.e. 'Uncategorized' isn't deleted.

Comment: Ok, in that case I would have to test the stuff (but don't have capacity right now). I suggest you try [Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) I think it supports term meta even in the free version(and even uses the term meta table if WP has it!) - and many more that will just ease your life. Still want to develop it yourself? => check [their code](https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/ac) if it's working for them... but I must warn you that code is quite generic and probably will use more advanced functions like `update_metadata` etc... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing might be due to the action hook you're using to save the term meta. The `created_category` hook fires after the term is created, but it doesn't ensure that all fields are available at that point.

To ensure that the term meta is being saved correctly even for the first category, you might want to use the `create_term` or `create_category` hooks. These hooks are fired after a new term or category is created in the database and all information is already available.

Here is how you might modify your code:

```
function mt_set_color_category_term_meta( $term_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['_term_color'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_term_color'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, '_term_color', sanitize_hex_color( $_POST['_term_color'] ) );
    } else {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, '_term_color' );
    }
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'mt_set_color_category_term_meta' );
add_action( 'edit_term',  'mt_set_color_category_term_meta' );
```

You may also want to consider using the `edit_term` action instead of edited_category for consistency and to ensure it works for all term types, not just categories. The `edit_term` action fires after a term has been updated, and it works for any taxonomy.

Comment: thanks. I tried that too and it results in the same behavior.